# How do i translate this SQL into LINQ? (Sorting by popularity)

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

EDIT: Based on one of the posts below, i figured out how to write it.  Answer is at the end of this post.

I have a store... and one of the dropdowns allow you to sort the products by popularity (items that are most purchased, show up first).

I know how to write this in SQL, but i'm failing miserably in LINQ.  Can someone translate this for me? Hopefully if I see enough of these examples, i'll get better at doing it myself...

I simply want to bring back all the items, but in order of popularity.  You can tell which are most popular by seeing how many times the itemId comes up in the "OrderDetails" table.

```
select i.*
from items i
left outer join (
    select od.itemid, ct = COUNT(1)
    from orderdetails od
        join orders o on od.orderid = o.orderid
    where o.ordersubmitteddate is not null
    group by od.itemid
    ) pop on pop.itemid = i.itemid
order by pop.ct desc, i.name
```

------ ANSWER BELOW -------

Here's the answer, I write one query first to determine which "items" i want to show... and then I write a second query to order it....

```
var items = db.Items.Where("STUFF");

items = from i in items
        join pop in (
            from od in db.OrderDetails
            where od.Order.OrderSubmittedDate != null
            group od by od.ItemId into g
            select new { ItemId = g.Key, Ct = g.Count() }
        ) on i.ItemId equals pop.ItemId into pop_join
        from x in pop_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
        orderby x.Ct descending, i.Name
        select i;
```

Comment: I would suggest you to install this tool for the future
http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could try

```
var pop =   from od in context.OrderDetail
            join o in context.Order on od.OrderId equals o.OrderId
            where o.OrderSubmittedDate != null
            group by od.ItemId into g
            select new { ItemId = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };

var query = from p in pop
            join i in items on p.ItemId equals i.ItemId into j
            from x in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
            order by x.Count descending, i.Name;
```

This should definitely get you in the right direction, but I can't guarantee this even compiles. The idea is that you *can* nest queries in LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Thanks... based on this... I put my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

```
from i in Items
orderby i.ItemOrderDetails.Count(o=>o.Order.OrderSubmittedDate!=null) descending
select i
```

If you don't have a relationship between items and order details, then you can do it like this:

```
from i in Items
orderby (OrderDetails.Count(d=>d.ItemId==i.Id && d.Order.OrderSubmittedDate!=null)) descending
select i
```

If you prefer to use as much query syntax as possible, you can also express it like this:

```
from i in Items
let OrdersSubmitted= 
( from d in OrderDetails
  where d.ItemId == i.Id 
  where d.Order.OrderSubmittedDate != null
  select d)
orderby OrdersSubmitted.Count() descending 
select i
```

The let statement is very handy for producing more easily readible linq statements.

Comment: unfortunately, there is no foreign key link from my items to order details... wouldn't that result in "circular" referencing (saw an error in SQL for that before, had to remove one of the foreign keys)

Comment: A circuit of relationships is not complete unless all the one to many joins point in the same direction (you can only traverse the join from the many side to the one side).

Comment: Hmm.. the edits seem promising.  I will revisit and come back to this post later...